# Symfony: The return type of method "X" in class "Y" is invalid

Tags: php, symfony, entity, symfony6

I recently added a new method to one of my Entities, which retrieves a related collection.  On compile, I got the following error:

```
The return type of method "getItems" in class "App\Entity\Order" is invalid.
```

My code follows:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="OrderItem", mappedBy="order", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $orderItems;

/**
 * @return Collection|OrderItem[]
 */
public function getItems(): ?Collection
{
    return $this->orderItems;
}
```

This seems like a straightforward addition, and it mimics (exactly) other collection retrieval methods in my code.  So... why the error?

Answer (score 1):

I searched way too long for an answer to this, and it turned out to be a simple fix...

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
```

Yep... instead of telling me that it couldn't find the `Collection` class that I was using for my return value, the error I got was "invalid return type."  I suppose that's technically correct (according to my `use` statements, this wasn't an option), but it's not particularly useful.

Hopefully this helps someone get an answer faster than I did!

Comment: This is one reason why many developers use IDEs.